# First page is blackened after adding watermark

Tags: pdfsharp

Page is blackened after adding watermark in case of some pdf files . Please see attached image.
What could be the reason , and possible fix.

see the blacked out page image
[image: see the blacked out page image]

It does not happen for all the files but for some files only.
[Code is here in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/muc7mB).

```cs
var _pdfInBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\test\\test123.pdf");
string watermarkText = "This watermark text on left side";
var coordinates = new Point(25, 200);
using (var pdfNewDoc = new PdfDocument())
{
    using (var pdfImport = PdfReader.Open(new MemoryStream(_pdfInBytes, true), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
    {
        if (pdfImport.PageCount == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var pg in pdfImport.Pages)
        {
            pdfNewDoc.AddPage(pg);
        }

        var page = pdfNewDoc.Pages[0];

        // overlapping trick #165910
        var xOffset = 100.0;

        for (var index = 0; index < page.Contents.Elements.Count; index++)
        {
            var stream = page.Contents.Elements.GetDictionary(index).Stream;
            var x = GetMinXOffsetDraft(stream.ToString());

            if (xOffset > x)
            {
                xOffset = x;
            }
        }

        xOffset *= 0.6; // magic number :)

        // blank page trick #165910
        if (page.CropBox.IsEmpty && !page.MediaBox.IsEmpty)
        {
            page.CropBox = page.MediaBox;
        }

        // Get an XGraphics object for drawing beneath the existing content
        var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);
        
        var tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
        
        var xFont = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);

        // Get watermark text size
        var wmSize = gfx.MeasureString(watermarkText, xFont);

        // Middle Y coordinate
        var wmY = (gfx.PageSize.Height - wmSize.Width) / 2;

        var coords = new XPoint(page.CropBox.Location.X + (xOffset < coordinates.X ? xOffset : coordinates.X),
            page.CropBox.Location.Y + (coordinates.Y > wmY ? coordinates.Y : wmY));

        // Define a rotation transformation at the center of the page
        gfx.TranslateTransform(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y);
        gfx.RotateTransform(90);
        gfx.TranslateTransform(-coordinates.X, -coordinates.Y);

        // Create brush
        var brushColor = Color.Red;
        var brush1= new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(brushColor.A, brushColor.R, brushColor.G, brushColor.B));
        brush1.Overprint = false;
        XBrush brush = 
            new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(brushColor.A, brushColor.R, brushColor.G, brushColor.B));
        
        var rect = new XRect(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, gfx.PageSize.Height - coordinates.Y,
            coordinates.X);

        tf.DrawString(watermarkText, xFont, brush, rect);
        byte[] outputBytes = null;
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pdfNewDoc.Save(outStream, false);
            outputBytes = outStream.ToArray();
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test\\test-"+DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyhhmmss") +".pdf", outputBytes);
        
            
            
private double GetMinXOffsetDraft(string v)
{
    var result = 100.0;

    using (var str = new StringReader(v))
    {
        var s = str.ReadLine();

        do
        {
            var sarr = s?.Split(' ');

            if (sarr?.Length == 7 && sarr[6] == "Tm")
            {
                var x = double.Parse(sarr[4]);
                x = x < 0 ? 200 : x;
                result = result > x ? x : result;
            }

            s = str.ReadLine();
        } while (s != null);
    }

    return result;
}    var _pdfInBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\\test\\test123.pdf");
    string watermarkText = "This watermark text on left side";
    var coordinates = new Point(25, 200);
    using (var pdfNewDoc = new PdfDocument())
    {
        using (var pdfImport = PdfReader.Open(new MemoryStream(_pdfInBytes, true), PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
        {
            if (pdfImport.PageCount == 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var pg in pdfImport.Pages)
            {
                pdfNewDoc.AddPage(pg);
            }

            var page = pdfNewDoc.Pages[0];

            // overlapping trick #165910
            var xOffset = 100.0;

            for (var index = 0; index < page.Contents.Elements.Count; index++)
            {
                var stream = page.Contents.Elements.GetDictionary(index).Stream;
                var x = GetMinXOffsetDraft(stream.ToString());

                if (xOffset > x)
                {
                    xOffset = x;
                }
            }

            xOffset *= 0.6; // magic number :)

            // blank page trick #165910
            if (page.CropBox.IsEmpty && !page.MediaBox.IsEmpty)
            {
                page.CropBox = page.MediaBox;
            }

            // Get an XGraphics object for drawing beneath the existing content
            var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);
            
            var tf = new XTextFormatter(gfx);
            
            var xFont = new XFont("Arial", 10, XFontStyle.Regular);

            // Get watermark text size
            var wmSize = gfx.MeasureString(watermarkText, xFont);

            // Middle Y coordinate
            var wmY = (gfx.PageSize.Height - wmSize.Width) / 2;

            var coords = new XPoint(page.CropBox.Location.X + (xOffset < coordinates.X ? xOffset : coordinates.X),
                page.CropBox.Location.Y + (coordinates.Y > wmY ? coordinates.Y : wmY));

            // Define a rotation transformation at the center of the page
            gfx.TranslateTransform(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y);
            gfx.RotateTransform(90);
            gfx.TranslateTransform(-coordinates.X, -coordinates.Y);

            // Create brush
            var brushColor = Color.Red;
            var brush1= new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(brushColor.A, brushColor.R, brushColor.G, brushColor.B));
            brush1.Overprint = false;
            XBrush brush = 
                new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(brushColor.A, brushColor.R, brushColor.G, brushColor.B));
            
            var rect = new XRect(coordinates.X, coordinates.Y, gfx.PageSize.Height - coordinates.Y,
                coordinates.X);

            tf.DrawString(watermarkText, xFont, brush, rect);
            byte[] outputBytes = null;
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdfNewDoc.Save(outStream, false);
                outputBytes = outStream.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\test\\test-"+DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyhhmmss") +".pdf", outputBytes);
   
            
            
            
private double GetMinXOffsetDraft(string v)
{
    var result = 100.0;

    using (var str = new StringReader(v))
    {
        var s = str.ReadLine();

        do
        {
            var sarr = s?.Split(' ');

            if (sarr?.Length == 7 && sarr[6] == "Tm")
            {
                var x = double.Parse(sarr[4]);
                x = x < 0 ? 200 : x;
                result = result > x ? x : result;
            }

            s = str.ReadLine();
        } while (s != null);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Which version of PDFsharp are you using? Can you share an affected PDF (before adding the watermark)?

Comment: 1.50.4740.0 is version , attached is affected pdf

Comment: Could you attach the offending pdf file?